# swift - cocoa class handling

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa

I'm new in swift-ios. I'm studying [this](https://www.ralfebert.de/tutorials/ios-swift-uitableviewcontroller/)

when I'm trying to create cocoa file,

> import cocoa

is giving error. 
I've searched in google and found cocoa class not work in ios-swift. it works in osx.

So I'm not getting what'll I do now. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Have you downloaded and read the sample code on the linked site to see how they do that?

Answer (score 1):

Cocoa is a framework for macOS. However, CocoaTouch is an umbrella module for iOS. To import the main module dependency for an iOS app, you use

```
import Foundation
```

And to import the main UI module for an iOS app, you use

```
import UIKit
```

Answer (score -1):

The term “Cocoa” has been used to refer generically to any class or object that is based on the Objective-C runtime and inherits from the root class, NSObject.

Comment: Cocoa is more of an API and is explicitly defined as an application development environment in the Apple documentation found here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Cocoa.html

Comment: yes its an API, but the question was to create a cocoa class file, thats why the answer is create a class file which inherits root class NSObject. Check the Note in the link which you posted.

Comment: The question directly correlates with Swift for iOS, which uses the CocoaTouch APIs. So one would have to import either the Foundation module or the UIKit module which would be included automatically by selecting New > File > CocoaTouch.

Comment: The error occurs because the OP started an iOS project but created a Cocoa file (macOS).

Comment: yes i know, I was just explaining what a cocoa file is, I didn't understand what exactly you find wrong in that.

Comment: Firstly, the snippet you've pasted doesn't answer the question at all; you don't mention a Cocoa file at all. Secondly, you should always site the source from which you've taken an answer. And finally (again), the OP's issue is using macOS binary in an iOS application environment.